# remove duplicates in a datatable

Tags: c#, algorithm, datatable

I have the following implementation to find duplicates in a DataTable . It is highly inefficient and takes forever on about 20K rows. I only have to find duplicate entries for the second column values:

```
private List<string> checkForDuplicates(DataTable results)
{
    List<string> duplicateLists = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Rows.Count; i++ )
    {
        string cellvalue = results.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        for (int j = 0; j < results.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
             if (cellvalue.Equals(results.Rows[j][1]))
                {
                    //Duplicate found                            
                    duplicateLists.Add(results.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "_" + i+2 + "_" + j+2);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return duplicateLists;
}
```

Comment: Have you got an index on the column you are comparing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've got is that every row has to check every other row, so with more rows the number of checks goes up exponentially. The quickest way to handle it is to make it linear - only do as many checks as there are rows.

One way to do this is to sort the data table by column2. This will put any duplicates in adjacent rows, so then you just need to run through the table checking that one row doesn't match the next one.

The other way is to get things at source and make sure the rows are distinct before you read them.

Comment: But sorting means also comparing values to each other, doesn't?

Comment: @bender. When unsorted this happens: Say you have 3 rows, then the number of checks is 3*3 = 9 (crudely, some of these might be omitted, but its broadly true). When you add another row you have 4*4=16 checks, then 25, 36 etc. So for 20K rows you have 400million checks.  When you sort then you only need to check one row against the next, so for 3 rows you need 2 checks. For 4 rows you need 3. For 20k rows you need 19,999 checks.  That's why you get such an improvement in performance.

Comment: @bender. In addition sorting itself does require some comparisons, but sort algorithms are extremely efficient and would require much much less than 400mill comparisons.

Comment: Yes I know, that sorting algorithms are faster than O(n2) (square). But they are slower than O(n). So your solution takes at minimum O(n log n). Check my Solution as well, since retrieving a value by key from a Dictionary takes only 0(1) and iterating over a list takes only O(n)....

Answer (score 1):

One optimisation you could make is to do the de-duplication on a sorted data set. Define a DataView which sorts the data on the relevant column, then simply check that the current row's value is not the same as the previous row's value.

Mark Sowul's answer might be a better idea if you aren't bothered about physically removing the rows however.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Dictionary and iterate once over all values and count the occurence of each value => Dictionary key is the column value, Dictionary value is the count.
Then return all keys where count is more than one.

Comment: This works well too, but I went with Jon's answer since his solution just feels more natural to me. The resulting code is pretty simple to understand and I'm dealing with about 20-60K rows. 60K rows felt like it would never finish with the old "compare all values" method where as sorting and checking adjacent records is almost instant, sort included.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataset/thread/ed9c6a6a-a93e-4bf5-a892-d8471b84aa3b

`DataTable distinctTable = originalTable.DefaultView.ToTable( /*distinct*/ true);`

For your purposes you could make a DataView that includes only the column(s) you're interested in.

Comment: Would that not distinct all columns rather than just column2?

Comment: Like I said you could make a DataView that includes just column2, or apparently you can call ToTable with a list of columns: DataTable uniqueTable = dvwDataView.ToTable(true, "name", "next_column_name", "another_column_name");

Comment: It would, Not what im looking for, Jon your first answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

SQL would be much more efficient way of doing this rather than pulling the entire dataset twice.

You can do it very quickly if you have an index on the column you are referring to.

Just do

```
SELECT id AS matchID, column1 FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN (SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE id IS NOT matchId)
```

or something like that

Cheers,
Niko